# Google Sheets Horizontal Radio checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to create radio checkboxes, i managed to make it work when the checkboxes are in vertical as shown in the exemple sheet bellow with the tab name 'Radio 1' but i have another tab 'Radio 2' where the checkboxes are aligned horizontally and are not aligned one after the other but after every 2 cells, the first Radio works with the following code

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.range.rowStart > 8 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
 let r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2,7);
  let checks = r.getValues();
  for (let i in checks){
    if(checks[i][0] == true && +i != e.range.rowStart - 2)
    checks[i][0] = false;
    }
  r.setValues(checks);
}
```

but i cant make it to work when adapting to the second radio tab, any ideas?

[sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=766179482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the cell ranges of checkboxes are used.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.
  // The cell ranges of checkboxes are set as A1Notation.
  const obj = {
    'Radio 1': ["B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8"],
    'Radio 2': ["H11", "J11", "L11", "N11", "P11", "R11"]
  };

  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  const a1Notation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (!obj[sheetName] || !obj[sheetName].includes(a1Notation) || e.range.getValue() === false) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(obj[sheetName].filter(e => e != a1Notation)).uncheck();
}
```

- When this script is run, when a checkbox is checked on "Radio 1" or "Radio 2", other checked checkboxes are unchecked.
- If you want to add "Radio 3" and others, please add them to `obj`.

#### Note:

- When you changed the checkboxes and the sheet names, please modify `obj`. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [uncheck() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#uncheck)

Comment: this perfectly fit my case, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == 'Radio 1') {
    if (e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.range.rowStart > 8 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
    let r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2, 7);
    let checks = r.getValues();
    for (let i in checks) {
      if (checks[i][0] == true && +i != e.range.rowStart - 2)
        checks[i][0] = false;
    }
    r.setValues(checks);
  }
  else if (sh.getName() == 'Radio 2') {
    var cel = e.source.getActiveRange()
    if (cel.getRow() == 11 && cel.getValue() == true) {
      var r = sh.getRange('H' + cel.getRow() + ':S' + cel.getRow())
      var checks = r.getValues()
      for (var i=0;i<checks[0].length;i+=2) {
        if (checks[0][i] == true && i != cel.getColumn()-8)
          if (checks[0][i]==true) {checks[0][i] = false};
      }
      r.setValues(checks);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to apply to multi-rows, change this `cel.getRow() == 11`

Comment: it worked like magic, the issue is that in my original sheet it was clearing the formula that had in the cells in between the checkboxes, but i managed to use the other solution left here inserting the columns in an array and using the exact values instead of looping through them, thanks anyways

Comment: In your sample, there were no formulas. Glad to know that you solve your problem.